# curl_multi_init and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION without class?

Tags: php, curl

I`m trying to use curl_multi_init but also I want to limit size of downloaded page and for it in past for standard curl call I have used CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION option but I can`t get it to work with curl multi without usage of CLASS, I have some examples but all of them using PHP CLASS for it...

How to add CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to this function:

```
function rolling_curl($urls, $callback, $custom_options = null) {

    // make sure the rolling window isn't greater than the # of urls
    $rolling_window = 5;
    $rolling_window = (sizeof($urls) < $rolling_window) ? sizeof($urls) : $rolling_window;

    $master = curl_multi_init();
    $curl_arr = array();

    // add additional curl options here
    $std_options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5);
    $options = ($custom_options) ? ($std_options + $custom_options) : $std_options;

    // start the first batch of requests
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rolling_window; $i++) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $urls[$i];
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch);
    }

    do {
        while(($execrun = curl_multi_exec($master, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        if($execrun != CURLM_OK)
            break;
        // a request was just completed -- find out which one
        while($done = curl_multi_info_read($master)) {
            $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200)  {
                $output = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);

                // request successful.  process output using the callback function.
                $callback($output);

                // start a new request (it's important to do this before removing the old one)
                $ch = curl_init();
                $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $urls[$i++];  // increment i
                curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
                curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch);

                // remove the curl handle that just completed
                curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $done['handle']);
            } else {
                // request failed.  add error handling.
            }
        }
    } while ($running);

    curl_multi_close($master);
    return true;
}
```

I`m trying many many things but simple all don`t working...I hope that somebody can help me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$options[CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION] = 'receiveResponse'; 

function receiveResponse($ch,$string) use (&$full_length) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    $full_length += $length;
    if($full_length >= 20000) { return -1; }
    return $length;
}
```